# Is there a simple PromQL statement used convert cumulative histogram into ordinal histogram?

Tags: prometheus, promql

As we known, the bucket metrics got from prometheus are cumulative histogram. Is there a simple PromQL statement used convert cumulative histogram into ordinal histogram?

For example:

```
http_access_bucket{node="aaa",le="5"} 20
http_access_bucket{node="aaa",le="10"} 30
http_access_bucket{node="aaa",le="20"} 35
http_access_bucket{node="aaa",le="50"} 38
http_access_bucket{node="aaa",le="100"} 40
http_access_bucket{node="aaa",le="+Inf"} 40
```

convert to:

```
temp_bucket{node="aaa",le="5"} 20
temp_bucket{node="aaa",le="10"} 10
temp_bucket{node="aaa",le="20"} 5
temp_bucket{node="aaa",le="50"} 3
temp_bucket{node="aaa",le="100"} 2
temp_bucket{node="aaa",le="+Inf"} 0
```

thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of such a function. For which exact use case you need it?

Btw, there is an alternative implementation of [histograms](https://valyala.medium.com/improving-histogram-usability-for-prometheus-and-grafana-bc7e5df0e350) in VictoriaMetrics and looks like their exposition format is close to what you're looking for:

```
vm_http_request_duration_seconds_bucket{path="/metrics",vmrange="1.000e-05...1.136e-05"} 4
vm_http_request_duration_seconds_bucket{path="/metrics",vmrange="1.136e-05...1.292e-05"} 1
vm_http_request_duration_seconds_bucket{path="/metrics",vmrange="1.292e-05...1.468e-05"} 4
vm_http_request_duration_seconds_bucket{path="/metrics",vmrange="1.896e-04...2.154e-04"} 2
vm_http_request_duration_seconds_bucket{path="/metrics",vmrange="1.000e-03...1.136e-03"} 1
vm_http_request_duration_seconds_sum{path="/metrics"} 0.0019834780000000003
vm_http_request_duration_seconds_count{path="/metrics"} 19
```

Comment: Thanks. I have many nodes. If I want to find which one of has a shot in metric in 50~100ms,  I must write a promQL to find it. If I want to find another node with a shot in 20~50ms, I have to write another. You recommendation is very useful. I'll study it.